# How to use SQLReader to return List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

We have a stored procedure that returns a single column of strings. We would like to use SqlHelper.ExecuteReader( ConnectionString,...) to return a list< string > but aren't sure of the syntax.

I should have been more explicit. I didn't want to have to loop through the reader and build the list myself. I was hoping for a more concise, 'one liner' or maybe some kind of casting that I was unaware of.

Comment: This SqlHelper? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/fd9229c0-53d0-4b3b-a7da-5df4047343a3

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586674/c-is-this-the-correct-way-to-use-the-sqldatareader-for-daab

Comment: Well it's not obsolete in the DNN world. In fact it's used all over the place in DNN versions 4 and 5. Don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: Curious as to the down vote....any helpful hints what not to do next time...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> AsEnumerable(this IDataReader reader)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader;
    }
}

...

using (var reader = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, query))
{
    var list = reader.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.GetString(0)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for something like this. We have several types of these queries and I was hoping for something more concise than looping through the reader.

Comment: @Gio, just a warning: don't try to do something like `reader.AsEnumerable().ToList()`, it won't work... all items in the list will refer to the last row. You need to extract the data while you're enumerating.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Retrieving Data Using a C# .NET DataReader](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html). The sample provides the solution for such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var sl = new List<string>();

// Edit accordingly
string sql = "";

// Edit accordingly
string cs = "Data Source= ;Initial Catalog= ;Integrated Security= ;";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        using (var dr = new command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var myRow = dr["MyColumn"];
            sl.Add(myRow.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```